# Texture coordinate into texel form?

Tags: directx11

How do I convert a texture coordinate, like 1,0 into a texel form(a single value?). Like in the image below, what is the value of Q22 in texel?[image]

I'm in directx 11.

Comment: What is the "texel form" of a coordinate?  Do you mean converting a uv-coordinate to a row-major linear offset?